# Calculate the area of the largest surface of a mesh with and without holes in Blender scripting

Tags: python, blender, mesh, bpy, bmesh

In Blender, I have a bunch of meshes with different shapes (cuboids, L-shapes, pentagons, hexagons, ...) with holes, see attached image. The meshes are not flat, not always vertical, have different orientations and they are volumetric (with thickness). I want to calculate the area of the **largest surface** with (bruto) and without holes (netto). I can calculate the area of all triangles but it's the total area not the area of the largest surface.

I have one solution, and it is selecting the largest face by area and then select the *coplanar faces* and then calculating the sum of their areas.
cons: Too many steps, only in Edit mode and is error-prone if the largest face is not on the largest surface.

And yet I don't know how to get the vertices of the boundary edges (the polygon of the largest surface) so I can calculate its area.

Any solution is appreciated. Also since I have the vertices and faces, if I can do it with another library/package (FreeCAD, OpenCascade) in Python it can be helpful.

[sample_file_obj_format](https://bimbuildingsbv791.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/ScanPlan/EaR4nX6LOf5PvraZH-U2FlwBM-Jxuuki9fSnXn-PwzQBjg?e=gBT5h6)

```py
import bpy
import bmesh
import numpy as np


def get_blend_lwh(obj):
    """
    get Length Width Height from a blender obj
    """
    dim = obj.dimensions
    l = max(dim[0:2])
    w = min(dim[0:2])
    h = dim[2]

    return l, w, h



def get_boundary(object):
    """ get boundary of the mesh """
    # This returns more vertices than the boundary!!!
    # ??? If I can get the polygon of the mesh (outer vertices) I can calculate the area with holes.
    
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(obj.data)

    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
    boundary = []
    for edge in bm.edges:
        if edge.is_boundary:
            coords = [vert.co for vert in edge.verts]
            boundary.extend(coords)

    # print(np.unique(np.asarray(boundary), axis=0)) # this sorts the points
    
    return boundary
    
def get_verts(obj):
    return [vert.co for vert in obj.data.vertices]


def select_coplanar_faces(obj):
    """ select coplanar faces """
    # To calculate the area of the largest surface without holes (netto)
    
    # get the index of the largest face by area
    inx = get_largest_face_inx(obj)
    
    # select coplanar faces of this largest face
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    obj.data.polygons[inx].select = True
    
    # select coplanar
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='COPLANAR', threshold=0.1)

    # HERE I don't know how to get the area of selected faces ???
    
    

def get_largest_face_inx(obj):
    """ get the index of the largest face """

    areas = [poly.area for poly in obj.data.polygons]
    
    return np.argmax(areas)


def get_largest_face_area(obj):
    """ get the area of the largest face """

    areas = [poly.area for poly in obj.data.polygons]
    
    return max(areas)


def get_total_area(obj):
    """ get Length Width Height from a blender obj """
    areas = [poly.area for poly in obj.data.polygons]
    
    return sum(areas)
    


# main()
obj = bpy.context.active_object
print(get_total_area(obj))
print(get_blend_lwh(obj))
print(len(get_boundary(obj)))
print(len(get_verts(obj)))

print(get_largest_face_inx(obj))
select_coplanar_faces(obj)
```

**UPDATE**

I modified `def select_coplanar_faces(obj)` method now it gives me the selected faces and I can get the area of them. But still, I don't know how to get the area of this surface with holes/openings.

```py
def select_coplanar_faces(obj):
    """ select coplanar faces """
    
#    # get the index of the largest face by area
    inx = get_largest_face_inx(obj)
#    
#    # select coplanar faces of this largest face
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    obj.data.polygons[inx].select = True  
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='COPLANAR', threshold=0.1)
    
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    coplanars = [f for f in bpy.context.object.data.polygons if f.select is True]
    
    return coplanar

# Main
coplanar = select_coplanar_faces_bmesh(obj)
print(coplanar)

print(sum([f.area for f in coplanar]))
```

[image]